# Only get duplicated values within groups with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame such as :

```
groups  ids numbers
group3  id4 89
group1  id1 50
group1  id1 30
group1  id2 90
group2  id4 89
group2  id6 76
group3  id4 90
```

and the idea it to find with `groupby` groups the duplicated ids and get a new data frame with only duplicated ids by groups such as:

```
group1  id1 50
group1  id1 30
group3  id4 89
group3  id4 90
```

I tried:

```
for groups in df.groupby('groups'):
 print(df['ids'].duplicated)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Function `groupby` is not necessary, for better performance use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) by multiple columns and parameter `keep=False` for get all dupes, then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['groups','ids'], keep=False)]
print (df)
   groups  ids  numbers
0  group3  id4       89
1  group1  id1       50
2  group1  id1       30
6  group3  id4       90
```

If sorting necessary add [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default index:

```
df = (df[df.duplicated(['groups','ids'], keep=False)]
         .sort_values(['groups','ids'])
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   groups  ids  numbers
0  group1  id1       50
1  group1  id1       30
2  group3  id4       89
3  group3  id4       90
```

Comment: Very close idea`df.loc[df.index.difference(df.drop_duplicates(['groups','ids'],keep=False).index)]
`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.groupby('groups').apply(lambda x: \
            x[x.duplicated('ids',keep=False)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   groups  ids  numbers
0  group1  id1       50
1  group1  id1       30
2  group3  id4       89
3  group3  id4       90
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help :)